# MQTT Session clean on node.js

Tags: mqtt

I'm use this code on node.js, and my mqtt server is cloudmqtt.

mqtt script result has a problem.

I must write clientid and click "Clear session" button.

If I didn't that, messages can't arrive each other.

I try find to "mqtt" on npm packages, but I can't found someting that how can clear sessions.

Can you teach me how can send message?

******write result*****

λ node test_cloudmqtt.js
mqtt2 connected
mqtt1 trigger called0
mqtt1 trigger called1
mqtt1 trigger called2
mqtt1 trigger called3
mqtt1 trigger called4
mqtt1 trigger called5
mqtt1 trigger called6
mqtt1 trigger called7
mqtt1 trigger called8
mqtt1 trigger called9
mqtt1 connected0
mqtt1 connected1
mqtt1 connected2
mqtt1 connected3
mqtt1 connected4
mqtt1 connected5
mqtt1 connected6
mqtt1 connected7
mqtt1 connected8
mqtt1 connected9
MSG : Hello mqtt0
MSG : Hello mqtt1
MSG : Hello mqtt2
MSG : Hello mqtt3
MSG : Hello mqtt4
MSG : Hello mqtt5
MSG : Hello mqtt6
MSG : Hello mqtt7
MSG : Hello mqtt8
MSG : Hello mqtt9

```
    var client1  = mqtt.connect(cloudmqtt.mqttHost, {
    port: cloudmqtt.MQTTPORT,
    username: cloudmqtt.mqttMasterId,
    password: cloudmqtt.mqttMasterPw});

function testmqtt(param) {
    console.log("mqtt1 trigger called"  + param.toString());

    client1.on('connect', function () {
        client1.publish('/kym_test', 'Hello mqtt' + param.toString());
        console.log("mqtt1 connected"  + param.toString());

        /*client1.end(function () {
            console.log("mqtt1 disconnect");
        });*/
    });

    client1.on('error', function () {
        console.log("mqtt1 error");
    });
}

var client2  = mqtt.connect(cloudmqtt.mqttHost, {
    port: cloudmqtt.MQTTPORT,
    username: 'kym2',
    password: 'xxxx'});

client2.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("mqtt2 connected");
    client2.subscribe('/kym_test');
});


client2.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log("MSG : " + message.toString());
});


for(var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
    setTimeout(testmqtt, 1000, a);  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the mqtt.js [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttclientstreambuilder-options) on npm

> - protocolId: 'MQTT'
> - protocolVersion: 4
> - clean: true, set to false to receive QoS 1 and 2 messages while offline
> - reconnectPeriod: 1000 milliseconds, interval between two reconnections
> - connectTimeout: 30 * 1000 milliseconds, time to wait before a CONNACK is received
> - username: the username required by your broker, if any

```
var client1  = mqtt.connect(cloudmqtt.mqttHost, {
    clean: false,
    port: cloudmqtt.MQTTPORT,
    username: cloudmqtt.mqttMasterId,
    password: cloudmqtt.mqttMasterPw});
```

Comment: I tried, but node.js occured problems. So, I added clientID that same to username. but result has problems even.

Comment: It would help if you posted and described the latest errors that you see.

Comment: If I didn't write ClientID, It's message shown.
So, I write ClientID same to username.

C:\Users\ES_SERVER\node_modules\mqtt\lib\connect\index.js:119
    throw new Error('Missing clientId for unclean clients')
    ^

Error: Missing clientId for unclean clients
    at Object.connect (C:\Users\ES_SERVER\node_modules\mqtt\lib\connect\index.js:119:11)

Comment: But, MQTT client message can't arrive each other yet.

Comment: "cloudmqtt" service give "clear session"button on Web UI. I write username and click the button. finally mqtt message is gone. I want to use only node.js